# How do I add time together?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am working on a timesheet program in C# where the user selects hours worked for a day from a combobox drop down list for each day the work.  The dropdown options are in 15 minute increments ( :15, :30, :45, 1:00, 1:15 and so on).  So on Monday, the user could select 5:30 (meaning he/she worked 5 hours and 30 minutes, not the time 5:30).  On Tuesday, the user could select 6:45 and so on for the week.

The Selected Item is for the total hours and minutes worked that day, not an interval of time or a specific point in time, but the total hours and minutes worked for the day.

How can I add the hours and minutes selected each day together to get a grand total for the week?

It is my understanding, the items in a combobox are strings, so I tried to convert the strings to DateTime, but that didn't work.  I tried converting the string to a decimal and then to DateTime, but I was unable to do that either.

How do I take those hours/minutes worked each day, and get a total for the week?

Help!?  I am losing my mind on this one!!  :)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input and help.  I was able (finally!!) to get the hours to add up by changing the type to TimeSpan, but I have run into another problem.  As I add up the hours for the week, when the total is over 24 hours, it rolls over to a day and not 25:00 etc.  I need it to add just the hours and minutes and keep in that format so I can calculate hours for the week, OT etc.  I am using the format (@"h\:mm"), but with or without that formatting, when the calculation gets to 24 hours, it turns into 1.00:00:00.  Any suggestions?  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to convert the strings to `DateTime`, but that didn't work.

Convert strings to integers, which represent minutes. Construct [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) objects from these integers, passing the integer for the middle parameter.

Add `TimeSpan` objects together using [`operator +`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.op_addition(v=vs.110).aspx). The result will give you the total time, expressed as a span of time, from which you can query hours, minutes, and even days, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The combobox item should be a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.90).aspx) which can be added together.

Comment: I thought a combobox item was automatically a string?  How do I make it a TimeSpan?  I tried taking the selected item and converting it to TimeSpan, but I received an error stating Convert does not contain TimeSpan.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this may be a workaround for the current situation, anyway keep it as a suggestion;

Let `timeList` be the list of string that you are getting as inputs(please use `0:15` for 15 minutes).

```
List<string> timeList = new List<string>();
timeList.Add("0:15");
timeList.Add("2:00");
timeList.Add("1:00");
timeList.Add("2:15");
timeList.Add("3:15");
timeList.Add("4:15");
```

Then you can process the result by using the following code:

```
TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan(0, (int)timeList.Sum(x => getMinutes(x)), 0);
```

Where the `getMinutes()`method is defined like the following:

```
public static double getMinutes(string timeIn)
{
    string[] components = timeIn.Split(':');
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(components[0]), int.Parse(components[1]), 0);
    return ts.TotalMinutes;
}
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vi6sAP)